# Setting a std::function variable to refer to the std::sin function

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, std

I've got a question about how to properly use the new C++11 `std::function` variable. I've seen several examples from searching the Internet, but they don't seem to cover the usage case I'm considering. Take this minimum example, where the function `fdiff` is an implementation of the finite forward differencing algorithm defined in `numerical.hxx` (which isn't the problem, I just wanted to give a contextual reason why I'd want to take an arbitrary function and pass it around).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "numerical.hxx"

int main()
{
    double start = 0.785398163;
    double step  = 0.1;
    int    order = 2;

    std::function<double(double)> f_sin = std::sin;

    std::cout << fdiff(start, step, order, f_sin) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Attempting to compile the above program gives me the error (in clang++)

```
test.cpp:11:32: error: no viable conversion from '<overloaded function type>' to
      'std::function<double (double)>'
        std::function<double(double)> f_sin = std::sin;
                                      ^       ~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/functional:2048:7: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: no overload of 'sin' matching
      'nullptr_t' for 1st argument
      function(nullptr_t) noexcept
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/functional:2059:7: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: no overload of 'sin' matching 'const
      std::function<double (double)> &' for 1st argument
      function(const function& __x);
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/functional:2068:7: note: 
      candidate constructor not viable: no overload of 'sin' matching
      'std::function<double (double)> &&' for 1st argument
      function(function&& __x) : _Function_base()
      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.7.1/../../../../include/c++/4.7.1/functional:2092:2: note: 
      candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Functor'
        function(_Functor __f,
        ^
1 error generated.
```

or from g++

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:11:45: error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function<double(double)>’ requested
```

As I understand the problem, it's because `std::sin` is implemented as a template class in the standard library, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to give enough of a specialization to get a function reference. I've also tried various things like using the new `auto` keyword, using `&std::sin` to get a pointer, etc., but they all give me the same type of error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`std::sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) is an overloaded function:  you must disambiguate which `std::sin` overload you mean:

```
std::function<double(double)> f_sin = (double(*)(double))&std::sin;
```

There are some cases where the compiler can disambiguate overloaded functions (e.g., if `f_sin` was of type `double(*)(double)`, the cast would not be required).  However, this is not one of those cases.

Comment: `std::function<Sig>` providing a `Sig*` or `Sig&` constructor overload would help, too.

Comment: Thanks. This does work (though sort of messily IMO) if I remove the first inner set of parentheses to have `(double(*)(double))&std::sin`.

Comment: Yes, those parentheses were extraneous and I've edited the answer to remove them.

Comment: As a follow up question, I guess, is where is the advantage of `std::function` over using C-style function pointers if the "C++-way" can't resolve overloads while the "C-way" can? I know that if I use `double (*func)(double)` in my definition of `fdiff` instead, I don't need an explicit cast when using `std::sin` as an argument while apparently I will need a cast if I define `fdiff` using `std::function`.

Comment: `std::function` supports arbitrary callable object types (e.g. it works with the result of a call to `std::bind`, a functor, or a stateful lambda).  Function pointers support none of these.

Comment: OK. I guess a nice piece of 'syntax-candy' would have been for the `std::function` declaration to be capable of resolving overloads as well. But now I know, and hopefully this question will help answer questions for others in the future (since I never came across something like this in my Google searching).

Comment: @jmert The typical way to avoid the double type definition is to use something like [`make_function`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825559/why-is-there-no-stdmake-function), where specifying the type can be omitted if it can be deducted from the argument.

Answer (score 2):

With lambda you will be always on safe side:

```
std::function<double(double)> f_sin = [](double arg) -> double { return std::sin(arg); };
```

Actually you can do better, if you can change `fdiff` or it is already accepting template parameter - not just `std::function<double(double)>`:

```
auto f_sin = [](double arg) -> double { return std::sin(arg); };
std::cout << fdiff(start, step, order, f_sin) << std::endl;
```

[UPDATE] This answer is new version, previous advice to use function template specialization was incorrect, since std::sin is not function template but set of overloaded functions.

Comment: I still get the same error message as I reported above with that change (this was one of the variations I have tried).

Comment: I was misleading by OP by: `"std::sin is implemented as a template class in the standard library"` ;) @JamesMcNellis of course your answer is then valid,

Comment: Sorry about the poor wording. I meant a template function, and this was based on looking at line 455 of the cmath header I have on my computer (g++ 4.7.1). Am I reading the header file incorrectly and it's not actually a template function?

Comment: @jmert No problem. A side note is that the right name is `function template` not `template function`. Same for `class template`,

Comment: I was incorrect... additional `sin` overloads were added in C++11... I've retracted all incorrect comments.  Sorry about that.