# Overloaded Functions and function type

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, overloading

I am reading C++ primer and my question comes from 14.8.3 Callable Objects and `function`. In the Overloaded Functions and `function` section, it says:

We cannot (directly) store the name of an overloaded function in an object of type `function`:

```
int add(int i, int j) { return i + j; }
Sales_data add(const Sales_data&, const Sales_data&);
map<string, function<int (int, int)>> binops;
binops.insert( {"+", add} ); // error: which add?
```

I believe it is quite obvious which `add` we want to add, at least for human I guess (there is only one call signature matches), but why the compiler cannot tell? Is it because how `function` type works underneath? Will it be fixed in later standard maybe?

Thanks.

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393285/stdfunction-fails-to-distinguish-overloaded-functions this what you are looking for?