# Call a functor with a specific function from an overload set

Tags: c++, c++17, overloading, overload-resolution

#### Context

In mathematics-related context, I'd like to define functors working on `<cmath>` functions. For the purpose of this question, we will be using [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) as our functor.

This is ill-formed [(live demo)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a62be3e66f2d66f):

```
std::invoke(std::sin, 0.0);
```

> (g++-8.1) error: no matching function for call to 'invoke(<unresolved overloaded function type>, double)'

Indeed, [`std::sin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sin) is an overload set and the compiler lacks the type information to choose one of those functions.

### Question

How could I name a specific function from an overload set? With what could we replace `LEFT` and `RIGHT` so that the following is well-formed and does what is expected (say, select `double std::sin(double)`)?

```
#include <functional>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    (void) std::invoke(LEFT std::sin RIGHT, 0.0);
}
```

If this is not possible, is there a way to define a functor so it is overload-set-aware?

Comment: it does have to be in the style with `LEFT` and `RIGHT` or would you be fine with assigning `std::sin` to a function pointer or `std::function` and then use that to call `invoke` ?

Comment: @user463035818 It needs to be nice at the caller site. `my_invoke<double(double)>(std::sin, 0)` is ok for instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [template type deduction failing (std::empty as a predicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566936/template-type-deduction-failing-stdempty-as-a-predicate)

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk This is not the same issue: your proposed dup is a template deduction failure; my question is "how to name a specific function from an overload set". There is an overlap between the two, but its not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way I know to do this is to use a lambda to enable overload lookup

```
std::invoke([](auto val){return std::sin(val);}, 0.0);
```

Will allow you to pass any value to `invoke` and then the lambda body will handle the actual call and overload resolution will come in then.

You can use a macro to abstract the lambda body out of the call to `invoke` using something like

```
#define FUNCTORIZE(func) [](auto&&... val) noexcept(noexcept(func(std::forward<decltype(val)>(val)...))) -> decltype(auto) {return func(std::forward<decltype(val)>(val)...);}
//...
std::invoke(FUNCTORIZE(std::sin), 0.0);
```

Comment: This is what I use, I hoped there were a way to provide syntactic sugar over that :/ I guess the more we have, the more we ask. Sugar is addictive.

Comment: @YSC FWIW, you could wrap this in macro, and I can add that to the answer if you want.  Hopefully we will also be getting [abbreviated lambdas](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0573r2.html) in one of the next standards.

Comment: I didn't know :)

Comment: Though if you're going to use a macro, might as well go all out and `auto&&...` and `-> decltype()` and `noexcept`.

Comment: No abbreviated lambdas I'm afraid :-(

Comment: Was rejected in 2017 ("voted out" to me implies that it was ever in)

Comment: @Barry Ah, yes.  That's a bummer :( I've updated the macro at least.

Comment: @Barry Good call using `auto&&...`.  I keep forgetting we can make lambdas variadic.

Comment: Add a std::forward in there. `auto &&` is a forwarding reference.

Comment: @peppe I've added that in.

Answer (score 3):

> How could I name a specific function from an overload set?

`static_cast`. E.g.

```
std::invoke(static_cast< double(*)(double) >( &std::sin ), 0.0);
```

There are easier ways to do around this, e.g. use a generic lambda to avoid that horrible syntax:

```
std::invoke([](auto x){ return std::sin(x); }, 0.0);
```

In Qt we've been bit pretty hard by the problem of taking the address of overloaded functions up to the point that [helpers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) have been introduced. I discussed a possible implementation of such a helper [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5/16795664#16795664).

Normative reference for the `static_cast` usage is [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#1.6).