# How to pass overloaded/template functions to algorithms in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++ we can't pass certain functions to algorithms. I suspect it's when they're overload or templates:

```
vector<string> xs = {"12", "34"};
vector<int> ys = transform_to_vec(xs, stoi); // compile error
```

The simplest workaround I've found is:

```
#define PLEASE(F) ([](auto&& x) { return F(forward<decltype(x)>(x)); })
vector<int> ys = transform_to_vec(xs, PLEASE(stoi));
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you can do it with a macro, you can certainly do it with a template..

Comment: @Brandon Good luck with that.  OP: this is the correct idiom to use.  Either write a lambda or write a macro that generates it for you.

Comment: FWIW you can make your macro slightly more generic/correct like I do here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54182576/4342498 (also might be considered a dupe target)