# C++ Passing templated functions to function

Tags: c++, function, templates, compiler-errors

I need to pass a templated function to a function.

Until now I haven't found any great advices on google.
This is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct event {
  bool signal;
};

template<typename T>
void out_stream(T &stream, event &evt) {
  stream << evt.signal;
}

template <typename F>
void doOperation(F f)
{
  event test;
  test.signal = 0;
  stringstream ss;

  f(ss, test);
}

int main() {

  doOperation(out_stream);

  return 0;
}
```

And that's the error the compiler gives me:

```
main.cc:27:3: error: no matching function for call to 'doOperation'
  doOperation(out_stream);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.cc:16:6: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'F'
void doOperation(F f)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Some (I hope) useful information about my g++ compiler setup:

- Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
- Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
- Thread model: posix

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: In your case, change `T` to `ostream` and remove the template. In general, wrap the function in a generic lambda.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182502/call-a-functor-with-a-specific-function-from-an-overload-set

Comment: Instead of accepting a template you could accept a function pointer with the type `template<typename T> using F = void (*)(T&, event&);` specialized for `stringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, you could help the compiler deduce `T` by calling `doOperation` with `out_stream<std::stringstream>`.

Also, within `doOperation`, you need to use `f` instead of `F`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/1shMs1ex8)

```cpp
#include <iomanip>  // boolalpha
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // stringstream

struct event {
    bool signal{};
};

template<typename T>
void out_stream(T& stream, const event& evt) {
    stream << std::boolalpha << evt.signal;
}

template <typename F>
void doOperation(F&& f) {
    std::stringstream ss{};
    f(ss, event{true});
    std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    doOperation(out_stream<std::stringstream>);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   true
```

As suggested in the comments though, other options you have instead of passing an instantiation of a function template are:

1. Change `out_stream` to accept a `std::ostream&`.
2. Pass a generic lambda that just calls the instantiation of the function template.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/5W3z8YK3r)

```cpp
#include <iomanip>  // boolalpha
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <sstream>  // stringstream

struct event {
    bool signal{};
};

void out_stream1(std::ostream& stream, const event& evt) {
    stream << std::boolalpha << evt.signal;
}

template <typename T>
void out_stream2(T& stream, const event& evt) {
    stream << std::boolalpha << evt.signal;
}

template <typename F>
void doOperation(F&& f) {
    std::stringstream ss{};
    f(ss, event{true});
    std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    doOperation(out_stream1);
    doOperation([](auto& stream, const auto& evt) { out_stream2(stream, evt); });
}

// Outputs:
//
//   true
//   true
```

Notice also there are no *templated functions*, but *function templates*. `out_stream` is a function template and needs to be instantiated with a given type, e.g. `out_stream<std::stringstream>`, to become a function. In the call `doOperation(out_stream);`, the compiler is unable to deduce the type to instantiate `out_stream` with.