# Why doesn't std::function participate in overload resolution?

Tags: c++, templates, translation, std-function

I know that the following code won't compile.

```
void baz(int i) { }
void baz() {  }


class Bar
{
    std::function<void()> bazFn;
public:
    Bar(std::function<void()> fun = baz) : bazFn(fun){}

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Bar b;
    return 0;
}
```

Because `std::function` is said not to consider overload resolution, as I read in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393285/stdfunction-fails-to-distinguish-overloaded-functions).

I do not fully understand the technical limitations that forced this kind of solution.

I read about the [phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) and [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) on cppreference, but I can't think of any reasoning that I couldn't find a counterexample to. Explained to a half-layman (still new to C++), what and during which stage of translation makes the above fail to compile?

Comment: @Evg but there is only one overload that would make sense to be accepted in OPs example. In your example both would make a match

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with "phases of translation". It's purely about the constructors of `std::function`.

See, `std::function<R(Args)>` doesn't require that the given function is *exactly* of the type `R(Args)`. In particular, it doesn't require that it is given a function pointer. It can take any callable type (member function pointer, some object that has an overload of `operator()`) so long as it is invokable *as if* it took `Args` parameters and returns something *convertible to* `R` (or if `R` is `void`, it can return anything).

To do that, the appropriate constructor of `std::function` must be a *template*: `template<typename F> function(F f);`. That is, it can take any function type (subject to the above restrictions).

The expression `baz` represents an overload set. If you use that expression to call the overload set, that's fine. If you use that expression as a parameter to a function that takes a specific function pointer, C++ can whittle down the overload set to a single call, thus making it fine.

However, once a function is a template, and you're using template argument deduction to figure out what that parameter is, C++ no longer has the ability to determine what the correct overload in the overload set is. So you must specify it directly.

Comment: Pardon me if I got something wrong, but how come C++ has no ability to distinguish between available overloads? I see now that std::function<T> accepts any compatible type, not only an exact match, but only one of those two baz() overloads is invokable **as if** it took specified parameters. Why is it impossible to disambiguate?

Comment: Because all C++ sees is the signature I quoted. It doesn't know what it is supposed to match against. Essentially, any time you use an overload set against anything that it isn't obvious what the right answer is *explicitly from the C++ code* (the code being that template declaration), the language forces you to spell out what you mean.

Comment: So the template parameter <void()> declares a family of compatible types and because of it being a "family" and not a single type I have to explicitly state what I'm matching against? Even though the overload set I specified contains only 1 proper match? Did I get it right?

Comment: @TuRtoise: The template parameter on the `function` class template is *irrelevant*. What matters is the template parameter on the *constructor* you are calling. Which is just `typename F`: aka, any type.

Comment: And the reason it's just F is because an overload set doesn't represent any specific type?

Comment: @TuRtoise: I think you're misunderstanding something. It's "just F" because that's how templates work. From the signature, that function constructor takes any type, so any attempt to call it with template argument deduction will deduce the type from the parameter. Any attempt to apply deduction to an overload set is a compile error. The compiler doesn't try to deduce every possible type from the set to see which ones work out.

Comment: "Any attempt to apply deduction to an overload set is a compile error. The compiler doesn't try to deduce every possible type from the set to see which ones work out." 
Exactly what I was missing, thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

Overload resolution occurs only when (a) you are calling the name of a function/operator, or (b) are casting it to a pointer (to function or member function) with an explicit signature.

Neither is occurring here.

`std::function` takes any object that is *compatible* with its signature.  It doesn't take a function pointer specifically.  (a lambda is not a std function, and a std function is not a lambda)

Now in my homebrew function variants, for signature `R(Args...)` I also accept a `R(*)(Args...)` argument (an exact match) for exactly this reason.  But it means that it elevates "exact match" signatures above "compatible" signatures.

The core problem is that an overload set is not a C++ object.  You can name an overload set, but you cannot pass it around "natively".

Now, you can create a pseudo-overload set of a function like this:

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define OVERLOADS_OF(...) \
  [](auto&&...args) \
  RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__(decltype(args)(args)...) )
```

this creates a single C++ object that can do overload resolution on a function name.

Expanding the macros, we get:

```
[](auto&&...args)
noexcept(noexcept( baz(decltype(args)(args)...) ) )
-> decltype( baz(decltype(args)(args)...) )
{ return baz(decltype(args)(args)...); }
```

which is annoying to write.  A simpler, only slightly less useful, version is here:

```
[](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto)
{ return baz(decltype(args)(args)...); }
```

we have a lambda that takes any  number of arguments, then perfect forwards them to `baz`.

Then:

```
class Bar {
  std::function<void()> bazFn;
public:
  Bar(std::function<void()> fun = OVERLOADS_OF(baz)) : bazFn(fun){}
};
```

works.  We defer overload resolution into the lambda that we store in `fun`, instead of passing `fun` an overload set directly (which it cannot resolve).

There has been at least one proposal to define an operation in the C++ language that converts a function name into an overload set object.  Until such a standard proposal is in the standard, the `OVERLOADS_OF` macro is useful.

You could go a step further, and support cast-to-compatible-function-pointer.

```
struct baz_overloads {
  template<class...Ts>
  auto operator()(Ts&&...ts)const
  RETURNS( baz(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) );

  template<class R, class...Args>
  using fptr = R(*)(Args...);
  //TODO: SFINAE-friendly support
  template<class R, class...Ts>
  operator fptr<R,Ts...>() const {
    return [](Ts...ts)->R { return baz(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); };
  }
};
```

but that is starting to get obtuse.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6eb33d93f3c0dce6).

```
#define OVERLOADS_T(...) \
  struct { \
    template<class...Ts> \
    auto operator()(Ts&&...ts)const \
    RETURNS( __VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...) ); \
\
    template<class R, class...Args> \
    using fptr = R(*)(Args...); \
\
    template<class R, class...Ts> \
    operator fptr<R,Ts...>() const { \
      return [](Ts...ts)->R { return __VA_ARGS__(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); }; \
    } \
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue here is there is nothing telling the compiler how to do the function to pointer decay.  If you have

```
void baz(int i) { }
void baz() {  }

class Bar
{
    void (*bazFn)();
public:
    Bar(void(*fun)() = baz) : bazFn(fun){}

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Bar b;
    return 0;
}
```

Then code would work since now the compiler knows which function you want as there is a concrete type you are assigning to.

When you use `std::function` you call it's function object constructor which has the form

```
template< class F >
function( F f );
```

and since it is a template, it needs to deduce the type of the object that is passed.  since `baz` is an overloaded function there is no single type that can be deduced so template deduction fails and you get an error.  You would have to use

```
Bar(std::function<void()> fun = (void(*)())baz) : bazFn(fun){}
```

to get force a single type and allow the deduction.

Comment: "since baz is an overloaded function there is no single type that can be deduced " but since C++14 "this constructor does not participate in overload resolution unless f is Callable for argument types Args... and return type R"  I am not sure, but I was close to expecting that this would be enough to resolve the ambiguity

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 But to determine that, it needs to deduce a type first, and it can't since it is an overloaded name.

Answer (score 2):

At the point the compiler is deciding which overload to pass into the `std::function` constructor all it knows is that the `std::function` constructor is templated to take any type. It doesn't have the ability to try both overloads and find that the first one doesn't compile but the second one does.

The way to resolve this is to explicitly tell the compiler which overload you want with a `static_cast`:

```
Bar(std::function<void()> fun = static_cast<void(*)()>(baz)) : bazFn(fun){}
```